# Remove specific Local user accounts from remote servers

Tags: powershell

We have a large number of servers with multiple accounts installed on the local machine, I need to remove the multiple local accounts from multiple servers and check they have been removed.

The only way I can see of doing this is by using PS-remoting (in our environment, it's totally locked down, so this is the only option)

As I understand you many new commands such as `Remove-localuseraccount` are only supported on new versions of PS (we have a project to upgrade to the better version)

```
$Computers = Get-Content C:\script\servers.txt

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

}
```

But what command can I run to check the multiple accounts list I have and remove if it finds any?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? Both Locally and on the Servers?

Comment: Remember, the command will execute with the version that is installed **on the remote computer** when using `Invoke-Command`. You always want to write a check for version before executing a remote command

Comment: Just a note the new user account cmdlets are only available on newer operating systems.  Win10 1607+ So upgrading PowerShell versions won't allow you to use the new cmdlets.

Comment: cheers peeps  im on ps version 5  the remote machines are 3,4

Answer (score 0):

## Desired State Configuration: Your life made easy

This will disable the local accounts and keep them that way utilizing DSC.

*Setup.ps1*

```
Install-Module -Name 'PSDscResources'
Set-Location -Path "$env:LocalAppData\Temp"
Configuration 'DisableDefaults'
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDscResources'
    Node 'localhost'
    {
        User 'Default'
        {
            Username = 'DefaultAccount'
            Disabled = $True
        }
        User 'Guest'
        {
            Username = 'Guest'
            Disabled = $True
        }
        User 'Admin'
        {
            Username = 'Administrator'
            Disabled = $True
        }
    }
}
DisableDefaults
```

*Execution.ps1*

```
Set-Location -Path "$env:LocalAppData\Temp\DisableDefaults"
$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\script\servers.txt'

$Sessions = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computers
Start-DscConfiguration -Path '.' -CimSession $Sessions -Wait -Force -Verbose
Remove-CimSession -CimSession $Sessions
```

You can cut the `CimSession[]` and just pass `-ComputerName $Computers`.  Also, you can utilize the `-Credential $PSCred` argument.

Comment: The account needs to be removed from the accounts list.

Comment: @Chill3r_chills You cannot remove default accounts, only disable them.

Comment: Hi, the account was created during build process, it isnt a default account.

Comment: @Chill3r_chills In that case, you can use `Ensure = 'Absent'` instead of `Disabled`.